# How to insert a floating-point number in the field of type DECIMAL for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, decimal

I have the field `field_name` with the following type `DECIMAL (10, 2)`. I want to insert a floating-point number in this field. I have the following SQL-query:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field_name` = "0,20" WHERE `primary_key` = 1;

SELECT `field_name` FROM `table_name` WHERE `primary_key` = 1;

>> 0.00
```

How do I write a floating-point number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a decimal point `.` instead of a comma `,`:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = 0.20 WHERE primary_key = 1
```

However, do note that the `DECIMAL` type is *fixed-point*, not *floating-point*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field_name` = 0.20 WHERE `primary_key` = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table_name` 
SET `field_name` = 0.20 
WHERE `primary_key` = 1;
```

It is called floating-**point**-number - so use a **point** instead of comma. And since it is no string you don't need the quotes around it.